# difference between out parameter and returned value in pl/sql

Tags: plsql

My understanding is there are 2 ways of returning retult from a procedure or function,

1. OUT type parameter: this is used to get values from procedures and functions
2. returned value from a function,

My question is,

1. what is the different between OUT parameter and returned value in a function?
2. If I have a OUT parameter in a function, does it mean I can have 2 "returned" result?

Comment: The answer to the second question is: YES. The first question is a very huge topic, to know similarities and differences please study the documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/subprograms.htm#i4074

Comment: What kind of difference are you thinking of? Obviously a function is something like `upper('x')` and a procedure is something like `dbms_output.put_line('x')`, and so the main difference is in semantics. Things like passing by reference, calling in SQL etc are details.

Answer (score 1):

Returned values from functions that has no out parameters can be used from SQL queries (inside a select or dml statement). If you have a code that returns a simple primitive type, i reccomend function.

```
SELECT * FROM PAYMENTS WHERE DATE = LAST_DAY_OF_MONTH(SYSDATE)
```

If you needs to return two or more related values, you can create a pl/sql object and return it in a function, and it can be used from plain sql too!

```
SELECT RESP.CODE, RESP.BODY FROM (SELECT GET_HTTP_RESP(URL) FROM DUAL) RESP;
```

Functions can be out parameters too, but that functions, like procedures, cannot be called from SQL queries.

If the code is really not supposed to be called from a SQL query, and you like to return not related values or values that not are the main objective  of that code, a procedure could be a good choice.

Not always you have a "correct" choice, is more like a programming style question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as suggested its a very huge topic but I can suggest some differences. Hope it Helps.

Answer :

1) Yes function can have multiple OUT IN params but the return type will be a constant. So if you have a OUT Param in a function so it cant be called in a SQL. Similarly FUNCTION without OUT param can be called in SQL.

2) You can use the OUT as well as RETURN type to get the values from FUNCTION but still return type remains only ONE.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FUNCT_TEST
(
p_in IN NUMBER,
p_out OUT NUMBER
)
RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
BEGIN
p_out:=10;
RETURN 'AVRAJIT';
END;


SELECT FUNCT_TEST(1) FROM DUAL;

ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'FUNCT_TEST'

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FUNCT_TEST
(
p_in IN NUMBER
)
RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
BEGIN
--p_out:=10;
RETURN 'AVRAJIT';
END;

SELECT FUNCT_TEST(1) FROM DUAL;

FUNCT_TEST(1)
AVRAJIT
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add and use as many `IN OUT` parameters in Functions like Procedure (Limit of IN OUT parameters in Functions/Procedures is 65536).

But if you have created the Function with `OUT` parameters you will get below error while accessing the function from `SELECT query`:

`ORA-06572: Function function_name has out arguments`